# Issue adding 3rd party modules to bundle

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to add [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/) and [pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) to my vendors bundle.

In `webpack.config.ts` I have:

```
entry: {
    main: './src/client',
    vendors: ['./node_modules/moment', './node_modules/pikaday']
},
output: {
    path: root('dist/client')
},
```

which `./src/client.ts` is the file I'm bootstrapping my `Angular2` module in (webpack entery point).

**The issue:**
I can define `moment` using:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

but the same approach doesn't work for `pikaday`, although both libraries are defined the same way through `commonJS`.

**Error message:**

> Cannot find module 'Pikaday'.

Comment: Not sure, but you it says `Pikaday` with a capital P. Perhaps you should use `import * as pikaday from "pikaday"` (without capital)

Comment: @PierreDuc I've tried that, it's not the issue.

Comment: Have you installed the typings? `npm install @types/pikaday --save-dev`

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes, I've installed them. actually,  I thought typings just add intelligence to editor/IDE. do they affect `webpack` build process too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webpack` gets an entry point and creates a graph of all dependencies based on how they're imported (required) into project. thus, it was enough to just have one entry point being `./src/client` and just import `Pikaday` wherever needed. then `webpack` will add `Pikaday` and because `Pikaday` requires `moment`, it will add `moment` to bundle. so I just removed `vendors` entry point to solve the issue.